# What minimum equipment is needed to generate a METAR + MOS?

Tags: metar

What specifically is the minimum equipment needed to generate a computerized METAR with:

1. Wind
2. Ceiling
3. Visibility
4. WX
5. Temp
6. DewPt
7. Altimeter
8. Density Alt
9. Clouds

and a MOS with:

1. Winds
2. Visibility
3. Clouds
4. Precipitation
5. Temp
6. DewPt

?

Comment: I had no idea what MOS is, [supposedly](https://www.pilotsofamerica.com/community/threads/taf-versus-mos.87343/#post-1929995) it's "a statistical model that is created to cover unmanned airports and provide some weather forecasting in more remote areas." Did you perhaps mean the more commonly used **TAF**?

Comment: TAF I believe is put together by a real individual and may use MOS to aid in forecast. MOS on the other hand is completely automated

Comment: I don't understand the purpose of this question. Obviously the answer is: *You need specialized equipment which can determine each of the relevant pieces of information* (except density altitude, which can be computed). No?

Answer (score 1):

[The METAR report has accepted abbreviations and format](https://www.wrh.noaa.gov/wrh/metar_decode_key.pdf) and you simply must report them in that format, how you gather that information depends on *what* you are reporting, a lot of the [regs can be found here](https://fsims.faa.gov/wdocs/8900.1/v03%20tech%20admin/chapter%2026/03_026_002.htm):

You can report [AWOS measurements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automated_airport_weather_station) which is information gathered from an [Automated Weather Observation System and (here in the US) is governed by this Advisory Circular](https://www.faa.gov/documentLibrary/media/Advisory_Circular/AC_150_5220-16E.pdf), your unit must adhere to those standards.

[ASOS systems are automated as well](https://www.thinkaviation.net/difference-between-atis-asos-awos/) and serve non aviation purposes beyond their aviation implications.

[You can report ATIS](https://www.thinkaviation.net/difference-between-atis-asos-awos/) which requires a human to actually confirm the measurements.

[ARTCC facilities have meteorologists assigned to them](https://www.faa.gov/air_traffic/publications/atpubs/aim_html/chap7_section_1.html) to provide specialized briefings and tailor forecasts.

[If you are just looking for a company that makes a compliant unit, heres one](https://www.allweatherinc.com/programs/faa-asos/)

---

The MOS reports are published by the NWS [and are not "measured" so much as they are computed](https://vlab.noaa.gov/web/mdl/mos), it requires forecasts, prior observations and geoclimatic data to compute. The NWS defines it as

> Model Output Statistics is an objective weather forecasting technique
> which consists of determining a statistical relationship between a
> predictand and variables forecast by a numerical model at some
> projection time(s). It is, in effect, the determination of the
> "weather related" statistics of a numerical model.